# Core data/Database IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, database, core-data

I'm new to IOS programming, and I have had a great time learning it. It took me about 4 months to really get a good grasp on it. I have began creating my own app, and I ran in to a few questions. The app I'm creating is a live app like instagram, foursquare, etc. How do I store all of the information I need. Can I use Core-Data to create a real-time app that can handle updates from multiple users?

Comment: You can use CoreData in any kind of app.

Comment: Take a look at https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic

Comment: Patrick - That looks awesome! Looks like i'll be diving into that tonight and the rest of the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The app I'm creating is a live app like instagram, foursquare, etc.
>   How do I store all of the information I need.

You'll probably create some sort of server to manage the data. Having a single, central source of data is a lot easier than trying to sync data between multiple devices.

> Can I use Core-Data to create a real-time app that can handle updates from multiple users?

You can -- Core Data works on MacOS X as well as on iOS, so you could write a Mac program that is the server for your iOS app. Whether that's the best approach is another question... I suppose it depends on how well you already know Core Data, whether there are any advantages to using the same Core Data data model on both the server and the client, how many clients you think you might have to support at once, etc.

If you're asking about using Core Data on the iOS client, then yes, you can certainly do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if the app has to support thousands of users at once sending updates etc. can core data handle that?

Comment: Too vague. Are you talking about the client side, or the server? What exactly does "thousands of users at once" mean? Does that mean that 2000 users are going to post updates at exactly the same instant, or that 2000 users will all be using the app at the same time? Are you just collecting information, or also fetching and returning information to the clients? The best way to get the answers you need is to prototype your project and run some tests. Also, keep in mind that you might not want to tie your server to a proprietary technology if you think you'll need to scale it up later.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness, but to your example, 2000 users will all be using the app in some capacity at the same time, and i'm fetching and returning information to the clients. I agree, I'm definitely in that prototype stage, just gathering information about how to go about the data phase.

Comment: @Caleb I agree that CoreData might be fine for client (though, not necessarily so; depends upon lots of issues). But I'm struggling to imagine too many scenarios where it would be the right server architecture, though.